# How to run Laravel project on Apache localhost

Tags: laravel-5

When I use artisan serve project works fine on localhost:8000 but I need to run project from localhost/, when I visit localhost/project/public code don't work correctly, any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Linux? If you are, then I have instructions for you that should help both for the current project and the future projects:

The best approach is to create a virtual host for your project. For future projects, you will simply repeat the same process.

To save you time, I have put together a clear tutorial on how to do so by creating a conf file. This will enable you to access your project by actually visiting a local domain like demo.local instead of localhost:8000 etc.

Here is the tutorial : [How to setup a virtual host in Ubuntu (Laravel Example)](http://simpledeveloper.com/how_to_setup_virtual_host_in_apache/)

I hope this helps and if you have further questions, please let me know.

Comment: I should not use port 8000 to access to project. I wana use standard 80

Comment: Good to hear it solved your problem; I have used it several times and it worked all the time!

Comment: I've followed as you mentioned in your tutorial but not working, can you help me what i have missing ?

Comment: You have which OS installed?

Answer (score 4):

Create a virtual host configuration file at

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

(Simply copy the default.conf file) and point the directory root to the folder containing your laravel project. Best is to copy your files to

```
/var/www/html/ ...project folder...
```

and make the public laravel dir document root in your confit file.

You can find more information on creating vhost files in many answers here on stackoverflow.